# Why removing the variable from the object's class during deserialization doesn't throw an Exception?

Tags: java, serialization

Why removing the variable from the object's class during deserialization doesn't throw an Exception? What does the "incompatible" changes mean in Serialization then?
I have also changed the field of the class from non-static to static which according to [Java Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/version.html#6519)

is incompatible.

Comment: You tried serializing an object which has a instance member & tried to de-serialize with class definition that has the member as static?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I did.

Comment: I had also removed one of the field during deserialization which didn't throw an exception either. 
NOTE: I have mentioned a Serial Version UID explicitly in my class.

Answer (score 3):

> Why removing the variable from the object's class during deserialization doesn't throw an Exception?

Because it isn't supposed to. See the [Object Versioning Specification, #5.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#5172):

> "Deleting fields - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its contract."

and

> "Changing a nonstatic field to static or a nontransient field to transient - When relying on default serialization, this change is equivalent to deleting a field from the class. This version of the class will not write that data to the stream, so it will not be available to be read by earlier versions of the class. As when deleting a field, the field of the earlier version will be initialized to the default value, which can cause the class to fail in unexpected ways."

Nothing there about throwing exceptions.

Comment: That bit only describes the reverse situation tho.

Comment: "If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value." How??? If I have asssigned a value for an instance of an object and then serialized it, the saved object should have the value. 
After that if I am deleting that instance from the original class, during deserialization the JVM should try to find the original field(which it couldn't find), and hence throw some Exception.
NOTE: It throws InvalidClassException when I'm changing the type of the instance.

Comment: If a value in the stream doesn't correspond to a non-static non-transient field of the same type it won't be stored anywhere. There is still no wording anywhere in the Specification that says an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @EJP: There is nothing mentioned about throwing an Exception either for changing the data type, though it throws an Exception.

Comment: There certainly is: "Changing the declared type of a primitive field - Each version of the class writes the data with its declared type. Earlier versions of the class attempting to read the field will fail because the type of the data in the stream does not match the type of the field.".

Comment: both deleting field in old generation and adding a field in new genration are practically same.they both would set default value in new generation then how one is compatible and one is incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

- I got such doubt in an **RPC** call, and I seemed to have found the answer.
- I added two fields and changed one field type of a class in the **server-side**, then the **client-side** calls a method which returns the old version class. First, I got an exception for the unmatched filed type, so I fixed this but leave the added fields, it works well, it confused me.
- Then I came here, I haved read the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#5172):

  - 5.6.1 Incompatible Changes - Deleting fields
  - 5.6.2 Compatible Changes - Adding fields
  - They talk about the same thing - the serialized byte codes do not contain the field of the deserializing object, while our codition is that the serialized byte codes contains some fileds but the deserializing object does not.
- **As I understand**:

  - From the consideration of design, such deserialization feature is very useful especially in an RPC call, serialization function should contain it.
  - Deep into the principle, deserialization instantiates an object of the client-side class(old version) and sets values of its fields(probabaly uses reflect to got a value of a field from the serialized byte codes), the redundant field in the serialized byte codes sits silently with no visiting.